# Local maxima and minima of $f(x,y,z)=(y+z)^2+(x+z)^2+xyz$

Tags: calculus, maxima-minima

I saw this exam problem but I'm having trouble how to determine the local maxima and the minima of this function.

This is what I did.

I found $f_x=2x+2z+yz \\
f_y=2y+2z+xz \\
f_z=4z+2y+2x+xy$

One stationary point I know it's $A(0,0,0)$ but  I can't find the others. I thought of using Sylvester's criterion.

$\Delta _1=f_{xx}=2 \gt 0 \\$

$\Delta_2= \begin{vmatrix} f_{xx} & f_{xy}  \\ f_{yx} & f_{yy}\\\end{vmatrix} $

$ \Delta _3= \begin{vmatrix}
    f_{xx} & f_{xy} & f_{xz} \\
     f_{yx} & f_{yy} & f_{yz} \\
    f_{zx} & f_{yz} & f_{zz} \\
    \end{vmatrix}$

For the point, $A$ I get $\Delta _2(A)=4 \gt 0$ and $\Delta _3(A)=0$. This is where I got stuck and I don't know what I should do. 
Can somebody help me find the other stationary points and help me to underestand what to do when I have the case $\Delta _3=0$?

Comment: The minimum does not exist and the maximum does not exist. Try $x=y=z\rightarrow+\infty$ and $x=y=z\rightarrow-\infty.$

Comment: Please clarify: Are your looking for all (local) minima and maxima, or do you only need the *global* minimum and maximum?

Comment: @MartinR You're right I'm looking for local minima and maxima

Answer (score 1):

$f(x,x,-x)=-x^3$ and $f(0,0,0)=0$. This shows: in each neighborhood of $(0,0,0)$ the function $f$ takes values $<0$ and values $>0$.

Consequence: in $(0,0,0)$ the function $f$ does not have a local extremum.

Comment: From WolframAlpha https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2x%2B2y%2Byz%3D0%2C+2y%2B2z%2Bxz%3D0%2C+4z%2B2y%2B2x%2Bxy%3D0, I got that there are no real zeros. But I don't know how to prove that

Answer (score 0):

All such candidates for maxima/minima can be found by solving$$f_x=f_y=f_z=0$$From $f_x=f_y=0$ we obtain$$2(x-y)=(x-y)z\\2x+2z+yz=0$$then either$$z=2$$which leads to $$x+y+2=0\\2x+2y+xy+8=0\\\implies xy=-4$$or finally$$(x_1,y_1,z_1)=(\sqrt 5-1,-\sqrt 5-1,2)\\(x_2,y_2,z_2)=(-\sqrt 5-1,\sqrt 5-1,2)$$The other candidates can be found$$x=y\\2x+2z+xz=0\\x^2+4x+4z=0$$$$x^2=4x$$therefore the candidates are$$(x_3,y_3,z_3)=(0,0,0)\\(x_4,y_4,z_4)=\left(-6,-6,-3\right)$$by investigating the eigenvalues of $H$ we obtain $(x_1,y_1,z_1)$, $(x_2,y_2,z_2)$ and $(x_4,y_4,z_4)$ are saddle points and $H(0,0,0)\succeq 0$ which can not be decided upon since the **second order sufficient condition (SOSC)** is not fulfilled.

Comment: Have you obtained $$\Delta=\begin{bmatrix}2&z&2+y\\z&2&2+x\\2+y&2+x&4\end{bmatrix}$$?

Comment: Thank you very much for the stationary points. But for the point $(x_1,y_1,z_1)$  I got $\Delta _2 =0$ which is inconclusive. How do you know that it's a saddle point? Also for $(x_4,y_4,z_4)$ I have $\Delta _1 \gt 0$ , $\Delta _2 \gt 0$ and $\Delta _3 \lt 0$ how did you conclude that it's a saddle point?

Comment: Based on the $\Delta$ I obtained for both $(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ and $(x_4,y_4,z_4)$ we have one negative eigenvalue and two positive eigenvalues.

Comment: $\Delta_2= \begin{vmatrix} 2 & 2  \\ 2 & 2\\\end{vmatrix}  =0$

Comment: And $(4,4,-\frac43)$ isn't a solution to this system. I got another point $(-6,-6,-3)$

Answer (score 0):

The second order condition $\Delta_3=0$ implies the test is inconclusive and one must use other techniques to classify the stationary point.

====================================================================

A simple example with $y=x^3$:
$$y'=3x^2=0\Rightarrow x=0 \quad \text{(critical point)}\\
y''(0)=6x|_{x=0}=0 \quad \text{(inconclusive)}$$
One method is to look at the small neighborhood of the critical point $x=0$:
$$f(0+\epsilon)=(0+\epsilon)^3=\epsilon^3>0\\
f(0-\epsilon)=(0-\epsilon)^3=-\epsilon^3<0$$
It shows that $f(0)=0^3=0$ is not a local maximum nor minimum, but an inflection point.

====================================================================

Similarly, given $f(x,y,z)=(y+z)^2+(x+z)^2+xyz$, consider the small neighborhood of the critical point $(x,y,z)=(0,0,0)$:
$$\begin{align}f(0+\epsilon,0+\epsilon,0+\epsilon)&=(2\epsilon)^2+(2\epsilon)^2+\epsilon^3>0\\
f(0+\epsilon,0+\epsilon,0-\epsilon)&=(0+\epsilon+0-\epsilon)^2+(0+\epsilon+0-\epsilon)^2+(0+\epsilon)(0+\epsilon)(0-\epsilon)=-\epsilon^3<0.\end{align}$$
It shows that $f(0,0,0)=0$ is not a local maximum nor minimum, but a saddle point.